# Javascript console output using Testacular, PhantomJS, Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

Is there some way I can write to stdout when running testacular headlessly(with PhantomJS and Jasmine), either by console.log() or some other mechanism? I understand that I can start up Firefox or Chrome and look at the log output there, but I'd ideally like to emit information in the test scripts for debugging or failure analysis.

Various docs seem to suggest that requiring 'system' will/may provide that ability, but RequireJS does not play well with the rest of the code which I'm trying to test (I get exceptions thrown from inside RequireJS).

Comment: What's the problem with `console.log`? I use `console.log` with PhantomJS scripts and everything works just fine: it's like printing to the stdout.

Comment: Are you using it with Testacular & Jasmine as well?

Comment: You should be able to see the output from console.log() in your chosen browser and in your console stdout no problem. The stdout for your console will not likely be as in depth as say chromes/firebug console for debugging (such as showing proto methods), but it gives a general idea of what your looking for.

Comment: is the problem in getting console output from the page into `phantomjs` or into `testacular` from `phantomjs`? or something else?